# Can you find an expression for $F_{12}(t,\tau)$ in terms of $F_{11}(t,\tau)$ and $F_{22}(t,\tau)$?

Tags: matrices, dynamical-systems, control-theory, matrix-equations

I have a problem with this...I can not figure out how to solve it..! can you help me? thank you!!

Show that if $A(t)$ is partitioned as

$$
A(t) =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  A_{11}(t) & A_{12}(t)    \\
  0         & A_{22}(t) &  \\
 \end{pmatrix},
$$

where $A_{11}(t)$ and $A_{22}(t)$ are square, then F(t,tau) is the transition matrix of the system such that:

$$
F(t,\tau) =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  F_{11}(t,\tau) & F_{12}(t,\tau)    \\
  0              & F_{22}(t,\tau) &  \\
 \end{pmatrix},
$$

where

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}F_{jj}(t,\tau)= A_{jj}(t)F_{jj}(t,\tau), \: j=1,2
$$

Can you find an expression for $F_{12}(t,\tau)$ in terms of $F_{11}(t,\tau)$ and $F_{22}(t,\tau)$?

Answer (score 0):

We can write the dynamical equations as follows:

$\begin{align*}
\dot{x}_1 (t) &= A_{11}(t) x_1(t) + A_{12}(t) x_2(t) \\
\dot{x}_2 (t) &= A_{22}(t) x_2(t)
\end{align*}$

Then we can write the following solutions:

$\begin{align*}
x_2(t) &= F_{22}(t, t_0) x_2(0) \\
x_1(t) &= F_{11}(t, t_0) x_1(0) + \int_{t_0}^t F_{11}(t, \tau) A_{12}(\tau) x_2(\tau) d\tau\\
&= F_{11}(t, t_0) x_1(0) + \left( \int_{t_0}^t F_{11}(t, \tau) A_{12}(\tau)F_{22}(\tau, t_0) d\tau \right) x_2(0)
\end{align*}$

Remember the solutions to the linear differential equations. Then we can write the following:

$\begin{pmatrix} x_1(t) \\ x_2(t) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} F_{11}(t, t_0) & F_{12}(t, t_0) \\ 0 & F_{22}(t, t_0) \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1(t_0) \\ x_2(t_0) \end{pmatrix}$

where

$\displaystyle F_{12}(t, t_0) = \int_{t_0}^t F_{11}(t, \tau) A_{12}(\tau)F_{22}(\tau, t_0) d\tau$

Hence, $F(t, t_0)$ is the solution of the original dynamical equation and $F_{jj}(t, \tau)$ is defined as in the question.